# Android CalendarView load custom data

Tags: android, calendar

I need to display custom dates/activities in an Android app. On ios I used [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) which allowed me to load JSON files in this [format](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal/blob/master/Examples/Holiday/support/holidays.json). So I need to display a calendar with some dates marked in it. Is there something similar for Android the CalendarView (api >= 11) does not support this as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up forking http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/ to add the features I wanted.